# How to filter Analytics data in Data Studio with parameters?

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I'm making a report in Data Studio using my Analytics data, and I'm having some trouble finding out how to filter it. Here is what I need to do:
I receive a "user" parameter in the URL, and I need to filter my "username" dimension with it. I want to make some kind of filter in the report, like Include usernameDimension = userParameter.

Comment: You should improve your answer. How are you passing parameters to your report? Are you using Report URL parameters and passing them in JSON format? (as explained in https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/data-source-parameters#set_url_parameters)

Comment: Yes I'm am!  @DiegoQueiroz

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For some limitation in DataStudio, currently it is not possible to directly use [Report URL parameters](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/data-source-parameters#set_url_parameters) for filtering reports (when you create a filter, it only allows you to select fields, not parameters).  However, it is possible to '*hack*' this limitation with a new field that references the parameter.

Create a new boolean field called `my_filter` (or something you wish) with this expression:

```
field_i_want_to_filter = my_parameter
```

Then, just create a new filter in your report using this field, with the condition `my_filter is true`.

Answer (score 0):

I can create a custom field to extract the username using a regular expressions.

Suppose you have a field called `URL` that contains something like:

```
https://example.com/path/path/endpoint?param1=blah&param2=bleh&username=Diego&param3=blih
```

You can use this formula in a new field to extract the username:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(URL, "[?&]username=([^&]*)")
```

You can easily add this custom field to a Drop down selector or something to allow filtering in your dashboard.

Comment: The URL comes from the embed, I already have it in a parameter. I don't want to put it in a dropdown, I need to compare it with the username dimension I already have, because it comes from the analytics.