# Google Data Studio URL Parameter not automatically updating a field that refers to it

Tags: looker-studio

I've been building a report in Google Data Studio that utilizes URL parameters going off of [this Google walkthrough](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/data-source-parameters#set_url_parameters). I am trying to pass a parameter into the report so that it filters the data in the charts and tables on the dashboard based on the groupID specified in the URL, going off of [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939295/how-to-filter-analytics-data-in-data-studio-with-parameters) which recommended

> Create a new boolean field called my_filter (or something you wish) with this expression:

> `field_i_want_to_filter = my_parameter`

> Then, just create a new filter in your report using this field, with the condition "my_filter" is true.

The issue here is that while the parameter itself is updated by the url with the relevant `params?=js_encrypted_value_here`, the parameter value that is calculated within the "my_filter" field is using the parameter's default value (currently set to 0) rather than to the parameter specified in the url.

[Here is a screenshot detailing the issue:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMawC.png)

The parameter is updated in the URL (circled in red) and that is updated in a control I added to the dashboard to check my work (also circled in red). However, urlGroupID has not changed from the parameter's default value of 0 (highlighted in yellow). The table also has a column labeled "filterField" which is a boolean field that returns "False" when urlGroupID != groupID and returns "True" when urlGroupID == groupID. Because "urlGroupID" retains the parameter's default value, "filterField" returns "false" for every row.

However, when I hit "enter" in the paramGroupID control, urlGroupID updates and the graph is populated with all the rows in the tabel that are marked true, [as seen in this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0eB5.png)

Is there a way that I can get "urlGroupID" to automatically update with the value in "paramGroupID" that doesn't require use input? Any help would be greatly appreciated, this tiny bug is breaking my brain.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the issue with a specific use case? Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (such as a code attempt that would provide a starting point for fellow users, a Google Day Studio Report to test out suggestions, etc) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue faced

Answer (score 0):

You can fudge the solution to this by utilizing [bookmark views](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7664330?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article).

When creating a bookmark view, the report will generate a URL that has a parameter in it, similar to how a parameter is generated in the URL when you change settings on the report to allow URL parameters to modify the report. However, this parameter will actively change control values in the report, unlike the method I attempted in my post above.